# Can a regex be used to calculate averages in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to write my gradebook in `sqlite`. Suppose my gradebook looks like this:

```
sqlite> select * from gradebook;
first   last       id    Quiz #1  Quiz #2  Quiz #3  Exam I  Exam II
------  ---------  ----  -------  -------  -------  ------  -------
John    Lennon     8401  87       57       80       55      65
Paul    McCartney  8190  88       55       45       59      60
George  Harrison   4144  97       91       76       68      59
Ringo   Starr      1325  58       95       91       77      80
```

To calculate my students' quiz average, I could do this:

```
sqlite> select first,last,("Quiz #1"+"Quiz #2"+"Quiz #3")/3 as "Quiz Average" from gradebook;
first   last       Quiz Average
------  ---------  ------------
John    Lennon     74
Paul    McCartney  62
George  Harrison   88
Ringo   Starr      81
```

However, I'm not happy with this because I will need to change the syntax as the students take more quizzes. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should change your datamodel such that the quiz results are rows not columns. Then you can apply aggregating functions like sum or average

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks for the idea. Is there a simple way to transpose the table I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current design, with only 1 table for everything, is already problematic and it will be more problematic in the future because you will have to add more columns to the table as you will have to store new grades for quizzes and exams.
The problem is not only the new columns but also that you will have to change the code that calculates averages.
It is obvious that you need a new design.

Start with a `students` table:

```
CREATE TABLE students(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT);
```

A `quizzes` table:

```
CREATE TABLE quizzes(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  student_id INTEGER REFERENCES students(id), 
  grade INTEGER, 
  description TEXT
);
```

And finally the `exams` table:

```
CREATE TABLE exams(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  student_id INTEGER REFERENCES students(id), 
  grade INTEGER, 
  description TEXT
);
```

Every row in the tables `quizzes` or `exams` corresponds to a column `Quiz #X` or `Exam X` value of the `gradebook` table.

You can populate the new tables directly from the `gradebook` table:

```
INSERT INTO students(id, first_name, last_name)
SELECT id, first, last
FROM gradebook;

INSERT INTO quizzes(student_id, grade, description)
SELECT id, `Quiz #1`, 'Quiz #1'
FROM gradebook
UNION ALL
SELECT id, `Quiz #2`, 'Quiz #2'
FROM gradebook
UNION ALL
SELECT id, `Quiz #3`, 'Quiz #3'
FROM gradebook;

INSERT INTO exams(student_id, grade, description)
SELECT id, `Exam I`, 'Exam I`'
FROM gradebook
UNION ALL
SELECT id, `Exam II`, 'Exam II'
FROM gradebook;
```

The 3 populated tables will be:

```
SELECT * FROM students;
```

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1325 | Ringo | Starr |
| 4144 | George | Harrison |
| 8190 | Paul | McCartney |
| 8401 | John | Lennon |

```
SELECT * FROM quizzes;
```

| id | student_id | grade | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8401 | 87 | Quiz #1 |
| 2 | 8190 | 88 | Quiz #1 |
| 3 | 4144 | 97 | Quiz #1 |
| 4 | 1325 | 58 | Quiz #1 |
| 5 | 8401 | 57 | Quiz #2 |
| 6 | 8190 | 55 | Quiz #2 |
| 7 | 4144 | 91 | Quiz #2 |
| 8 | 1325 | 95 | Quiz #2 |
| 9 | 8401 | 80 | Quiz #3 |
| 10 | 8190 | 45 | Quiz #3 |
| 11 | 4144 | 76 | Quiz #3 |
| 12 | 1325 | 91 | Quiz #3 |

```
SELECT * FROM exams;
```

| id | student_id | grade | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8401 | 55 | Exam I |
| 2 | 8190 | 59 | Exam I |
| 3 | 4144 | 68 | Exam I |
| 4 | 1325 | 77 | Exam I |
| 5 | 8401 | 65 | Exam II |
| 6 | 8190 | 60 | Exam II |
| 7 | 4144 | 59 | Exam II |
| 8 | 1325 | 80 | Exam II |

When you want to get the averages, you will join the tables and aggregate:

```
SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name,
       ROUND(AVG(q.grade), 2) AS avg_grade
FROM students s LEFT JOIN quizzes q
ON q.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id
```

and:

```
SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name,
       ROUND(AVG(e.grade), 2) AS avg_grade
FROM students s LEFT JOIN exams e
ON e.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=467b9866f37dbd2db13f3adf47a38520).

Comment: This is extremely helpful. I've been struggling to find a good way to manage my gradebook for a long time and eventually stumbled across sqlite. I'm completely new to databases and this answer puts me on the right track. Thank you!